# Zend 2: problems with Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I created a small function to test Zend-Ajax interaction.

In my view I set following code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var urlform = '<?php echo $this->url('inbox/default', array('controller'=>'messages', 'action'=>'addmessage')); ?>';
</script>

<div onclick="ajaxtest();">Click</div>
```

Then, I created following function within file custom.js, already associated to the layout

```
function ajaxtest() {

$.post(urlform, null, function(data) {
    if (data.success) {
        alert('Ok');
    } else {
        alert('Failed');
    }
}, 'json');

}
```

And finally, this is the code of my addMessageAction

```
public function addMessageAction()
    {
        $request = $this->getRequest();
        $response = $this->getResponse();

        $response->setContent(\Zend\Json\Json::encode(array('success'=>1)));
        return $response;
    }
```

When I click on the div associated to the javascript function, nothing happens, no alert is displayed.

Where am I wrong? Does it depend on particular zend settings?

Comment: Check out developer tools (F12) and Network tab to figure it out. You should see your call and the reason why nothing happend

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit inexperienced about. Which specific information I have to check? I don't see any post request..

Comment: You must have seen that in the `Network` tab. In `Console`, enter `ajaxtest` and let us know what result do you find.

Comment: I managed to see post request within Network tab. The post url seems correct, but the only not empty tab related to the post call is headers and cookie, all the others (Post, Html, Cache) are empty.

Response headers:

Connection Keep-Alive
Content-Length 0
Content-Type text/html
Date Mon, 07 Jul 2014 20:31:33 GMT
Keep-Alive timeout=5, max=98
Server Apache/2.4.9 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1g PHP/5.5.11
X-Powered-By PHP/5.5.11

Comment: with the code you typed. what are you posting?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by ridefining function in the following way:

```
var ajaxpost = $.post(urlform2).fail(function() {
    alert("Failed");
})

ajaxpost.done(function(data) {
    var parsed = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
    if (parsed.success == 1) {
        alert('Ok');
}
});
```